# How to fix 22: error: not found: value SparkSession in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I would like to read a CSV-file to a Dataframe.

Spark 1.3.0 / Scala 2.3.0

This is what I have so far:

```
# Start Scala with CSV Package Module
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0

# Import Spark Classes
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sqlCtx ._

# Create SparkConf
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("local").setMaster("master")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

# Create SQLContext
val sqlCtx = new SQLContext(sc)

# Create SparkSession and use it for all purposes:
val session = SparkSession.builder().appName("local").master("master").getOrCreate()

# Read CSV-File and turn it into Dataframe.
val df_fc = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/Desktop/test.csv")
```

However at `SparkSession.builder()` it gives the following error:

[image]
                     ^

How can I fix this error?

Comment: By doing that I am getting another error: "error: object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
       import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession"

Comment: There is no `SparkSession` in Spark 1.3 (really, it is reached its end-of-life years ago). If you want to use `SparkSession` update Spark to 2.0 or later.

Comment: oops I didn't read the question correctly thanks @user6910411

Comment: Ah ok. Then I'll update that. Thank you @user6910411!

Answer (score 0):

SparkSession is available in spark 2. No need to create sparkcontext in spark version 2. sparksession itself provides the gateway to all .

Try below as you are using version 1.x:

```
val df_fc = sqlCtx.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/Desktop/test.csv")
```